# Find the residue of $f(z)=\frac{1-\cos z}{2\sin z-\sqrt{3}}$ at $\pi/3$

Tags: complex-numbers, residue-calculus

Find the residue of $f(z)=\frac{1-\cos z}{2\sin z-\sqrt{3}}$ at $\pi/3$.

Here is my attempt:
The Taylor series for $\cos z$ and $\sin z$ about $z=\pi/3$ are
\begin{align*}
    \cos z &= \frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{3}(x-\pi/3)-\dots
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
    \sin z &= \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}+\frac{1}{2}(z-\pi/3)-\dots
\end{align*}
Thus
\begin{align*}
    f(z) &= \frac{1/2+\sqrt{3}/2(z-\pi/3)+1/4(z-\pi/3)^2-\dots}{(z-\pi/3)-\sqrt{3}/2(z-\pi/3)^2-1/6(z-\pi/3)^3+\dots}
\end{align*}
But I can't cancel anything out and get a finite pole. 
I know the answer is supposed to be $1/2$ but I don't know how to get there from here, since although $\lim_{z\to\pi/3}f(z)(z-\pi/3)=1/2$, the degree of the pole doesn't seem to be finite.

Comment: Hint: multiply the numerator and denominator of your last expression by
$$\frac{1}{z - \pi/3}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We want to find the residue of
$$ f(z)=\frac{1-\cos\left(z+\frac{\pi}{3}\right)}{2\sin\left(z+\frac{\pi}{3}\right)-\sqrt{3}}=\frac{1-\frac{1}{2}\cos(z)+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\sin(z)}{\sin(z)+\sqrt{3}\cos(z)-\sqrt{3}} $$
at $z=0$. Since in a neighbourhood of the origin we have $\sin(z)=z+o(z^2)$ and $\cos(z)=1-\frac{z^2}{2}+o(z^2)$, the problem is equivalent to finding the residue at $z=0$ of:
$$g(z)=\frac{1-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}z}{z+\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{3}}.$$
Such a residue is obviously $\color{red}{\frac{1}{2}}$.